# Background color to fit content on <p> tag

Tags: html, css

**Scenario :**

- I can't figure out how to have a 50% opacity "box" behind a text that just cover the text and not a whole square.
- I have a h2-tag that i have specified this CSS to:

  `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   width: fit-content;`

**Problem :**

- I tried the same thing on a p-tag, but that does not work...

Comment: Can You share your snippets

Comment: How do I do that @HariomSingh?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working fine.  Check This

```css
h2{
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
width: fit-content;
}

p{
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Text Here</h2>

<p>Some Text Here</p>
```

Comment: @PHPandSQL123 check this answer

Comment: https://www.bergans.com/About-us/Bergans for example here, when you put background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); and width: fit-content; on the p-tag here , it will show the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

if you want color behind the text then use `<mark>` tag

```css
mark{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<mark> test</mark>
```

Comment: Nah, but it is a fixed p-tag there :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
p{
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0 , 0.5);
   opacity: 0.5;
}

<p>Hello world</p>
```

This is works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an inline element like `<span>` and apply the same color to this inline element. Other wise you can apply display:inline to your `<p>`.

```css
p{
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris purus risus, tincidunt vel accumsan et, tempus placerat nisi. Suspendisse ornare, elit vitae vulputate pulvinar, arcu mi pretium lorem, et ultricies elit purus interdum nulla. Suspendisse vel erat id tellus venenatis viverra. Donec et mauris efficitur<p>
```

Hope this is you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.back {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <h2>This is h2 text</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>
```

Please check the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{
background-color:lightgreen;
margin:10px;
}

p.p{
background-color:lightpink;
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
<p class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
<p class="p">Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.</p>
<p class="p">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<p class="p"> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the `<p>` inline. See below snippet.
This also work with `width: 100%;`.

```css
p {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>
hello world
</p>
```